# Is there any way to get an id in a create method in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass a foreign directly to my create method

In the project I am working on, I have two different users. The first one is a farm who can create an animal
The second one is the clinic who can attach to an animal some clinic details showing if the animal was vaccinated or not. In my clinic details table, I have the animal as a foreign key but I do not know how I will pass that key to the create method

Here is my Clinic controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Animal;
use App\Clinic;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ClinicController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = Animal::all();
        return view('clinic.index', compact('user', 'animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function create($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = Animal::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $clinic = new Clinic();

        return view('clinic/create', compact('user', 'animal', 'clinic'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $animal = Animal::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('clinic.show', compact('animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My clinic index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><h3>Clinic Details Dashboard</h3></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        You are logged in! {{ $user->name}}
                            <hr>
                            <center><h3>Animals</h3></center>
                            <hr>
                            @foreach($animal as $animal)
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">{{ $animal->id }}</div>
                                    <div class="col-4"><a href="/clinic/{{ $animal->id }}">{{ $animal->type->category }}</a></div>
                                    <div class="col-2">{{ $animal->user->name }}</div>
                                    <div class="col-4">{{ $animal->created_at }}</div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

my clinic show.blade.php
This is where I would like to pass the animal id to the create method but I do not know how.
Even my button link is not going to the create view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Details for animal ')
@section('content')


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <center><h3>Details for the animal</h3></center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p><strong>Id: </strong>{{ $animal->id }}</p>
                            <p><strong>Animal: </strong>{{ $animal->type->category }}</p>
                            <p><strong>Farm: </strong>{{ $animal->user->name }}</p>
                            <p><strong>Gender: </strong>{{ $animal->gender }}</p>
                            <p><strong>Place Of Birth: </strong>{{ $animal->placeOfBirth }}</p>
                            <p><strong>Date: </strong>{{ $animal->created_at }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                            <a href="create">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Attach Clinic Detail
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

clinic create.blade.php
This view is still somehow empty

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Add Clinical Details')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">New Animal</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ url('clinic') }}" method="POST">


                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I believe you want to access the id inside of the create method. Have you tried passing the ID as a hidden input from the form?

Comment: I can. the problem is for the user I can because I will extract it from auth but for the animal where am I getting the id from

Comment: Because you have set your create method to accept a param, do something like this on your browser hostname/clinic/create/4 where 4 is supposed to be thy dynamic id. Inside of your page, just echo the id. If it shows, then you don't have a prolem with your code

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a parameter to your method like this:

```
public function create($id, $foreignKeyId) {
    // ... to something 
}
```

For that you would need to pass id as a hidden input.

You could also try to create a relation, that way you do not need to add the foreignKey as a parameter. You could simply access the foreign_key using the specified ORM Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **insertGetId()** method for retrieving last created id after store method.

https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId

```
$id = DB::table('posts')->insertGetId(
    array('title' => 'my post title', 'body' => 'my post body')
);
```